# LogicApps Web API making it Asynchronous

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, azure-logic-apps

I had to write a Web API to insert data into custom on-premise DB and then call a stored procedure for LogicApps to use.  The LogicApps' call timeouts when passing large amopnts of data.  So I'm trying to use this solution I found here:
[LogicAppsAsyncResponseSample](https://github.com/jeffhollan/LogicAppsAsyncResponseSample)

So I would basically put all my code into the doWork like this:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
  ...
  //Insert record
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
...
//Call SP
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

runningTasks[id] = true;
```

My question is should I make my code in doWork, asynchronous?  Use Await as needed and ExecuteNonQueryAsync instead of ExecuteNonQuery and add AsynchronousProcessing to my connection string?

Alternatively, too I was actually considering writing this to be "Fire and Forget".  Meaning I would start a thread in my API to call doWork as in the sample and return OK instead of Accepted right away. Then I wouldn't need to store thread statuses or have the chekcStatus method. This is OK for me since the API can send alerts if anything fails. The only advantage to the noted sample is I can eventually return something to LogicApps indicating success or not and show it in my LogicApps' log (one place to see all). Is "Fire and Forget" a sound practice?

FYI: the call to dowork in the sample is:

```
new Thread(() => doWork(id)).Start();
```

Comment: Few questions - how large is the data you are trying to return?  I'm guessing you are seeing the request to SQL takes > 90 seconds and then times out?

Comment: Yes.  When inserting 40 some rows and doing look ups etc, it task about 2 minutes.  There is much more being done in the foreach and the SP can take a 10-30 seconds too.

Comment: The new Thread call is returning an error by Code Analysis.

Error CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

So would changing it to be this, be better:
      await Task.Run(() => DoWork());

Comment: Sorry forgot to get back to this. If you don't need the response back from API I would do async. Should be a sound practice assuming you handle threads correctly. Would reduce complexity of integration and is used with some of our built in connectors too.

Comment: But if doWork is being handled by a Traditional Thread.Start, would doWork, even need to be Async?
Also in the case of "Fire and Forget", I would think I wouldn't need to handle the Thread.  Once doWork was done, the API is done, there would be no response back to the LogicApps.  I wouldn't need to do anything in the main routine after starting the thread except to return OK right away.

Comment: Likely correct. Depends on how your code is architected but yes above statements are correct.